# Creating resource group fails with "does not have authorization"

Tags: azure

I've been stepping through MS Azure training docs for quite a while now.  I find that the exercises consistently work.  However, today I was going through "Run Docker containers with Azure Container Instances Exercise - Run Azure Container Instances", and I'm getting a consistent error.

The first step, where I have to run this:

```
az group create --name learn-deploy-aci-rg --location eastus
```

Consistently fails with:

```
The client 'live.com#xxxxxx@gmail.com' with object id
'xxxxxxx' does not have authorization to
perform action
'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope
'/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/learn-deploy-aci-rg'
or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
refresh your credentials.
```

I tried logging out of the training account and logging back in, but I get the same result when I attempt this again.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is you are going to create a new resource group and it fails due to a permissions issue. You would need to have owner permission to the relevant subscription to create resource groups.

Answer (score 0):

As I have been reading your question You are trying to learn about *DockerContainers* ...... **nice!**, but the problem is the restrictive permissions that Microsoft implements if you run that **CLI-CODE** from *MicrosoftLearnArticles*.


So, Microsoft create a "Resource" denominated *"SandBox"* and in this SandBox, the resources that you create is only for educational purposes and another people use this for other purposes for that resources like to evade paying for expansive resources or use to make illegal things throw the resources created by the SandBox on the MicrosftLearn; and Microsoft undertand this and they decided to low the permissions for the CLI-CODE runed via that Microsoft articles that you had mencioned obviously harming the learning for the honest people like you :).


My recomendation *(in my low experience as student)* buy azure credits, or add your credit card or debit card or your student account and create your own services for learning pronounces and creating the resources on that "fair play" Microsoft must to offer you the respective support if you are having a problem because that support is included on the licensing guide.


That´s all.


I hope I have helped you.